# how to integrate java or other language with ethereum or solidity or web3js?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I am new to blockchain.
I have to implement one use case where user meta information will store in MySql Database and receptive unique id store in blockchain Database.

I am in confusion, how to integrate java or other language(to store in mysql) with etheruem or solidity or web3js(to store data in blockchain)?

Anyone have idea please guide me.

Thanks inadvance

Raja

Answer (score 2):

There are some options for you:

1. [Ethereum(J)](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj) is the library that can be embedded in any Java/Scala project to provide full support for Ethereum protocol and sub services.
2. See [Ethereum JSON-RPC documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC). You can use any JSON-RPC client available for Java.
3. If you would like to try other languages you can use [Python implementation](https://github.com/ConsenSys/ethjsonrpc) or NodeJS that uses official web3 library.

Comment: I created the [web3j](https://github.com/web3j/web3j) library for hooking Java applications up to Ethereum nodes/clients, so you don't need to think about doing the JSON-RPC integration yourself from your application.